# Bootstrap thumbnail - JQuery EqualHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want 3 thumbnails with equal height. If I first load the site the thumbnails are too small for the pictures and the text is behind the next row of thumbnails. The buttons are in the picture, if I reload the site they are all on same height and aligned.
why?

`HTML`:

```
    <div class="row equalheight">
        <div class="col-md-4 artikel">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Head</h3>
                    <p>Text</p><br><br>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg button" role="button">Click!</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 artikel">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Head</h3>
                    <p>Text</p><br><br>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg button" role="button">Click!</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 artikel">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Head</h3>
                    <p>Text</p><br><br>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg button" role="button">Click!</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
<script src="../../style/js/jQuery.equalheights.min.js"></script>

<script>
    if ($(window).width() > 960) {
        $('.equalheight div').equalHeights();
    }
</script>
```

`CSS`:

```
.button {
position: absolute;
bottom: 15px;
right: 30px;
}
.artikel {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Comment: can you please move your `equalHeights` call inside `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your height equalizer code into $(window).load() or $(document).ready() block.
Loading of images lags from the rest of the html. Your equalizer starts working before the images have fully loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 960) {
     $('.equalheight div').equalHeights();
    }
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 960) {
     $('.equalheight div').equalHeights();
    }
});
```